# How do Webpack & Next.js coordinate the execution order of async scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser, next.js, deferred-loading

When JavaScript is loaded asynchronously in the browser (via script tags with the async attribute), there is typically no way to control the order it executes.

With webpack, and frameworks like Next.js that load all scripts asynchronously ([example](https://next-learn-starter.now.sh/)), it seems like a Webpack runtime is loaded synchronously that coordinates all of the scripts. Each additional script asset is prefixed with a `webpackJsonp`. That is about as far as my understanding goes, but I'd like to learn more. Can anyone add some additional color or point me in the right direction to articles / docs / other resources?

Jake Archibald talks more about this topic here but it hasn't been updated in a while: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: I'd assume since they're using a prefix of `webpackJsonp`, they're using the old JSON-P method of loading, which is to just append a bunch of script tags and call this global function from those scripts so that it can be tracked when they're totally loaded and ready.

Comment: Ok. Do you know where i could read more about how the global function works? The signature usually looks like: `(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[1],{1234: function(){ //i do something }})`. I am curious how the logic for `1` and `1234` works. Also what's the purpose of throwing in `[1]` to the push function?

Comment: > old JSON-P method of loading
what would be the new / current way?

Comment: JSON-P was something that would be used to get around cross-origin restrictions for AJAX requests before CORS/`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was supported.  It might be a valid way to handle your use case... I'm not sure, I don't use those loaders.